# How to change image Orientation in imagePicker (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imageview, orientation

How can I change the image orientation when taking a photo using the image picker function. I am not trying to rotate the imageView. I just want the image taken to be displayed in the imageView upside down using the image orientation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate   {
@IBOutlet var displayImage: UIImageView!


var currentImageView: UIImageView?
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.currentImageView?.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true)



}


@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {


    self.currentImageView = self.displayImage

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}}
```

[image: errors from answer]

Comment: currentImageView is a optimal value for different imageViews. It is not the best use of code because there is only 1 imageView which is displayImage.  But in the future I want to use more than 1 imageViews.

Comment: I am not trying to store a image. I am just trying to change the orientation of the image. Could you go into more detail about what you having trouble understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question really directly, you can either rotate the `UIImage` itself or rotate the `imageView`. Here I've written you a function that you can implement in an extension of `UIImage` that will flip the image upside down.  Very simple to use, though without more context I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for.  You may also lose some quality.

```
public func flipped() -> UIImage {
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
    transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage, let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace, let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(self.size.width), height: Int(self.size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else { return self }
    context.concatenate(transform)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
    guard let transformed = context.makeImage() else { return self }
    return UIImage(cgImage: transformed)
}
```

Put that in an extension of `UIImage`, and all you have to do to use it is change your `UIImagePicker` delegate method assignment to `self.currentImageView?.image = image.flipped()`.

Comment: I think this close but I am getting 4 error messages. I added a picture to show you the errors. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JasonStone yes, you need to put that function in an extension of UIImage. Create a new empty file and type `extension UIImage { }` paste that function between those curly braces (and remove the one you put in your other file) and it should work.

Comment: Right now this image is only being rotated by 90 degrees. How could I rotate this by 270 degrees.